# Delete files in a directory, one at a time

Tags: batch-file, cmd, window, wildcard, delete-file

I want to create a batch file that will delete files with a specific extension in a directory, one at a time, something like

```
cd /D %Directory
FOR ???
    del *.myextension /Q  (but delete only one file, whichever it is)
    ping 192.0.2.2 -n 1 -1 1000 > nul (wait 1 second)
```

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
for %%i in (*.myextension) do (
    del /Q %%i
    ping 192.0.2.2 -n 1 -1 1000 > nul    
)
```

Comment: @Endoro seriously - It meets what the OP has asked for - whether it's unsafe, they should really be deleted, or even should be pinging that IP address is up to them...

Comment: you have no experience, so if you post here it is your risk, a high rist to be wrong and take the consequences. The meaning of the OP is without any importance, he is not a pro. You should remove your answer.

Answer (score 1):

the following code is **not safe**:

```
for %%i in (*.myextension) do (
    del /Q %%i
    ping 192.0.2.2 -n 1 -1 1000 > nul    
)
```

Outputexample:

```
>dir /b
abc.doc
abc.docx

>for %i in (*.doc) do @echo del "%~i"
del "abc.doc"
del "abc.docx"
```

Imagine you would only delete your old `DOC`  files and the batch will kill all new `DOCX` files also!

---

You should uns only my ***safe code***:

```
>for %i in (*.doc) do @if /i "%~xi"==".doc" echo del "%~i"
del "abc.doc"
```

for use in a batch file:

```
for %%i in (*.doc) do if /i "%%~xi"==".doc" echo del "%%~i"
```